# How to correctly chain promises that all involve the mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I am a beginner at Node and Mongo so I need some help. I am practicing with chaining promises and with MongoDB. I want to chain together 2 insert actions. However, when I run this code file, I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
    at /Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/MEAN Practice/Guru99/E8/mongopractice5.js:12:22
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
"
The error says that the problem is with this line of the code: "var db = client1.db('EmployeeDB')". However, I am unsure why this line will return an error. I know that MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }) returns a promise but is this promise in some way different from the promise returned by the first .then(...)?

```
var Promise = require('promise')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true        }).then(function(client) {
     var db = client.db('EmployeeDB')
     db.collection('Employee').insertOne({
         Employeeid: 4,
         EmployeeName: "NewEmployee"
     })
    client.close()
}).then(function(client1) {
    var db = client1.db('EmployeeDB')
    db.collection('Employee').insertOne({
        Employeeid: 5,
        EmployeeName: "NewEmployee1"
    })
    client1.close()
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: seems you dont return anything from the first `then` try to log client1 , i guess its undefined.

Comment: In the second `.then()`, 'client1' will be undefined and `client` is out of scope. You need to read [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/3478010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection and the inserts return promises.  Those are chained with the `then` method.  It's also desirable, IMO, to build functions that do discrete tasks and return promises, so...

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

function mongoConnect(url) {
    return MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
}

function mongoClose(db) {
    return db.close();
}

function insertEmployee(db, employee) {
    return db.collection('Employee').insertOne(employee);
}

function insertSomeEmployees() {
    let db;
    return mongoConnect('mongodb://localhost:27017').then(result => {
        db = result;
        return insertEmployee(db, { Employeeid: 4, EmployeeName: "NewEmployee" });
    }).then(() => {
        return insertEmployee(db, { Employeeid: 5, EmployeeName: "NewEmployee1" });
    }).then(() => {
        return mongoClose(db);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }); 
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between client and db? does client hold all the databases available? (is there a term for what the client holds?)

Comment: I copied that from the OP code, figuring it was something you needed.  Most mongo client usage I've seen needs only the db from the connect call.  I'll edit it to match common practice.

Comment: @JenniferZhou edited.  Note that this version only refers to the "Employee" collection in the db, and makes no reference to "EmployeeDB' in the OP

Comment: Re the other answer: promises are native in JS now.  Also note the other answer is playing a little loose with async, starting two inserts more or less simultaneously and not knowing when either one finishes.  Normally, we want to do some things strictly before or after other things, so we build  promise chains to control that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Promise = require('promise')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}).then(function(client) {
   var db = client.db('EmployeeDB');
   db.collection("Employee").insertOne({
       Employeeid: 4,
       EmployeeName: "NewEmployee"
      }).then(function(res) {
         console.log('Document inserted');
    });

    db.collection("Employee").insertOne({
        Employeeid: 5,
        EmployeeName: "NewEmployee1"
      }).then(function(res) {
        console.log('Document inserted');
     });
 }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
 })
```

---

You should close after every request ends.

And u are not using the promise library which you have imported.

Comment: So I guess I do not need to require('promise') then. How come I can use the then function?

Comment: @JenniferZhou It's a method of the object, not a static function that you would need to import (or have defined globally).